# Subtype of all object literal types in typescript?

Tags: typescript

assume `strictFunctionTypes` is turned on, so that function params are checked contraviariantly

```
interface Func<T> {
  (p: T): unknown
}
declare let b: Func<{p1: string}>
declare let c: Func<{p2: number}>
declare let d: Func<{p3: number, x: boolean, x1: number}>
// e, f, g... like before
let a: Func<U> // to make b, c, d, e, f... etc all assignable to a, what should U be
a = b
a = c
a = d
```

`a` should be assignable to all possable cases with form `Func<{x: 1, y: string}>`, there are infinity possible number of valid values, I currently can only find `any` as a valid value for `U`. And curious about the existence of a more constrained one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`U` needs to be a type which contains all other types, so be an intersection of all types:

```
let a: Func<{p1: string, p2: number, p3: number, x: boolean, x1: number}>
```

Comment: There are infinity possible value to assign to `a`, sorry for misleading, I updated my problem description.

Comment: There is no possibility to be type safe in your case. You can only do the merge of argument types like - `let a: Func<Parameters<typeof b>[0] & Parameters<typeof c>[0] & Parameters<typeof d>[0]>`.